# Has anyone worked with Immersion haptics UHL library?

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

I'm trying to get the vibration motor to run in different intensities. I have tried a pwm-like algorithm to use vibrate(pattern[], index), but it doesn't seem to work. the vibrations get very weak at 0.5 therefore there's no smooth increase transition in the intensities.

I have heard that Immersion's SDK has direct access to the hardware and magnitudes or levels of intensity can be achieved there.

Does anyone have any experience with that? is the library really usable?

Thanks!